# Can we use infinitive to after (has/have/had) been with the same meaning when we use gerund?

Tags: present-perfect

I took this sentence below from Oxford English Grammar Intermediate by Swan.

> **I've been to sleep three times during this lesson.**

I've never seen that construction before. What I've seen so far is

> **(Has/Have/Had) + been + (adjective/gerund)**

Why do they use infinitive there? Does it still have the same meaning if the infinitive form is replaced by gerund?

I mean:

> **I've been sleeping three times during this lesson.**

Comment: Your cited context is rather peculiar. In practice, I think for that *exact* context, a native speaker wouldn't use the Present Perfect for your first example - it would normally be Simple Past *I **fell asleep** three times during the lesson*. Note that it's not idiomatic to say *I've been [doing something] three times* (but it's fine to say something like *I've been doing it three times a week*. And it's also okay to say *I've been jogging three times* (where "jogging" is a gerund rather than a continuous verb, and the assertion implies an unstated ***...in my entire life*** or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what might be confusing you is that this similar to the idiom [**to go to sleep**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20to%20sleep), meaning "to fall asleep", and you should think of *sleep* here as a noun, not a verb, and *been* means the same thing as *gone*.  So you see that it's not a to-infinitive, but *to* a place or activity.  We could use this construction with other nouns, too, like

> I've been to the doctor three times

or

> I've been to soccer practice already this week

Your suggested version, *I've been sleeping three times during this lesson* doesn't really make sense or mean the same thing as the original sentence, because the progressive tense describes a *continuing* action, like

> I didn't hear what the professor said, because I was sleeping.

but the original sentence means that I went from being awake to being asleep three separate times.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special example of *been* as effectively the perfect of *go*.

We usually use it for travelling:

> I've been to France.

means roughly the same as

> I went to France and came back.

This construction is only used with *been*, not other parts of *to be*: you can't say *I am to France* or *I will be to France* in Modern English.

Where the "going" is metaphorical, rather than literal, you can use this pattern as well, as long as there has been a (metaphorical) return, so:

> He's been to hell and back!

*Go to sleep* is such an idiom (meaning "start sleeping") so the same pattern applies:

> I've been to sleep.

means

> I went to sleep and woke up again.